# References for Kleinian Groups

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I am keen in learning hyperbolic manifolds and Kleinian groups. Can anyone please suggest me references for Kleinian groups? I know (I maybe wrong) that there are four faces of Kleinian groups: 1. algebraic (as groups), 2. geometric (geometry of the hyperbolic manifold/orbifold, 3.  topological, 4. dynamical.

I am looking for  the geometric approach. Please advise me.

Comment: See [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-6720-9_2).